# I want the code to limit what it echos to only echo results that state "online"

Tags: php, boolean, echo

I want the code to limit what it echos to only echo results that state "online"
when it sends to unity however still shows all the results

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    //show data for each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if($row['online'] = "online")
        {
            echo "ip:".$row['ip'] . "|name:".$row['name']. "|usercount:".$row['usercount'] . ";";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have one very simple mistake. Change this line:

```
if($row['online'] = "online")
```

to:

```
if($row['online'] == 'online')
```

Comment: YAY!!! it worked thats lot easier then trying have unity limit it down thankyou still newbe

Comment: @Darkal - another improvement would be to include this condition within your SQL query, so save having to filter the results afterwards.