# PHP Condition after Mysql SUM

Tags: php

Hello so i am trying to get the sum of a column in the mysql db is its 0 preform query 1 else query 2

Problem is it always goes to the first condition not the else even when value from mysql phpmyadmin shows 1 or 2 as if there is a problem in the if condition

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "****";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

    $search = $_GET['search'];
    $sqlx = "SELECT SUM(`verified`) AS value_sum FROM Numbers WHERE `number` = ".$search." ";
    $resultx = $conn->query($sqlx);
    $sum = $row['value_sum'];

    if ($sum == 0)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Numbers` WHERE (`number` LIKE '%".$search."%' or `name` LIKE '%".$search."%') and `blocked` = 0 and `verified` = 0 GROUP BY `name` Limit 20";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
    else
    {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Numbers` WHERE (`number` LIKE '%".$search."%' or `name` LIKE '%".$search."%') and `blocked` = 0 and `verified` = 1 GROUP BY `name` Limit 1";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
```

Comment: Because you are **assigning** to `$sum` rather than comparing **against** it. Use `==` or `===` instead of `=`.

Comment: You have `group by` with `select *`.  Clearly you have problems with the queries.  That is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you explain what is the meaning of anti-pattern?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh I don't know why my answer was downvoted, but I recommend you treat it like a bool and just test if true or false like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48455140/1026996

Comment: @AhmedSaleh . . . A really bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$sum = 0` is an assignment so $sum will become 0. Fix all comparisons with `==` ie `$sum == 0`

As suggested in the comments take a look at

[The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: i changed it yet now it only goes to if not the else i am testing with value 1 and value 0

Comment: What is the actual query returning? $sqlx?

Comment: the query from mysql phpmyadmin returns a column with one row value either 0 or more

Comment: In your script there is no sign of where `$row` is coming from. It is output the first time after `$resultx = $conn->query($sqlx);` out of nowhere,also the `$conn` object . Where are they coming from? Please show the full script and output the actual result from the `$sqlx` query. People cannot guess what is happening on your machine.