# Display and hide an class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display and hide a div class using JavaScript, so that when someone hits a button a hidden section displays/hides dependent on the state/style. I've managed to display the hidden section, but I can't then hide it again. Here is the code I am using is a file called locationMenu.js.

```
const locationLink = document.getElementsByClassName('locationLink')[0];

locationLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
if (display = "none") {document.getElementsByClassName('locationMenuDropdown')
[0].style.display = 'block';}
else {document.getElementsByClassName('locationMenuDropdown')[0].style.display 
= 'none';}
});
```

and here is the (simplified) HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="locationMenuDropdown">
    <h3>Choose a Location</h3>
    <div class="locationButtons">
      <div class="et_pb_button"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Kettering</div>
      <div class="et_pb_button"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Northampton</div>
      <div class="et_pb_button"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Wellingborough</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="locationMenu"><h4 class="locationLink"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Locations</h4>
  </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="locationMenu.js"></script>
```

Comment: The `getElementsByClassName()` function returns a **list** of elements.  You have to iterate through the list and operate on each element individually.

Comment: Well, he is targeting only the first element in this list by indexing `0` with `getElementsByClassName('locationMenuDropdown')[0]`, so there is no error here, but you are mainly right ... using `getElementById()` would be the better choice to prevent errors

Comment: Where is button tom in your html

Comment: @Dipakchavda — They are using an `<h4>` instead of a `<button>`. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in the if condition, you are setting display to "none". The problems here are 2:

1- The display variable doesn't exist so the JS interpreter instace a new variable with that name;

2- The condition that u were trying to verificate is always true cause the = is the assignment symbol and not the equality ( == )

i think the best options to get the job done is

```
const locationLink = document.getElementsByClassName('locationLink')[0];

var divToFade = document.getElementsByClassName('locationMenuDropdown')[0];

locationLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
if (divToFade.style.display == "none") 
{
divToFade.style.display = 'block';
}
else 
{
divToFade.style.display = 'none';
}
});
```

See JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ja3xjw6c/6/

Comment: Thank you Davide! That worked. Interestingly, I now have to double-click the button in the first instance to display the hidden <div>, but after that, one-click is OK. But the way that is written makes perfect sense :)

Comment: See the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ja3xjw6c/12/ 
Then you dont need to double click :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (display = "none")
> ```

There are two problems here.

1. You haven't defined `display`. Elsewhere you use `document.getElementsByClassName('locationMenuDropdown')
   [0].style.display`
2. `=` is an assignment, not a comparison. It will always be true. See [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: Thanks Quentin, the == and the link are super helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Why aren't you using jQuery? then you could simply do this:

```
$('.locationLink').click(function(){
    $('locationMenuDropdown').toggle();
});
```

Comment: [Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)

Comment: Thanks Menno, just getting my head around JavaScript... JQuery is on my 'to try and understand soon list :D