# how to constantly change display property with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, properties

**Script:**

```
  let menu =  function(){
        var obj = document.getElementById("hidden")
        if(obj.style.display = "block"){
           obj.style.display = "none"
       //hide the div element with an ID #Hidden
        }else{
           obj.style.display = "block"
       //else show it 
        }
      }

        // I tried using buttons too, same result.
```

**CSS**

```
div#hidden{
       display:none;

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:menu()"id="info" > INFO </a> 

<div id="hidden">
     <!-- some stuff -->
</div>
```

I'm trying to "constantly" change the display property of my DIV element with an ID "hidden" to show and hide -VICEVERSA

[my javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwvNk.png)

Apparently this code runs but!
it won't run or do anything to my code the second time this event is called.

*the codes inside the if statements are executed but doesn't do anything or change my display property*

Comment: You need to post your code **in the question**, with relevant markup and in a snippet so we can run it.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] *in the question itself*, preferably as a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Don't just link to fuzzy pictures of text.

Comment: Also, `=` sets a value.  `==` compares values.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**see code below:**

```js
function func(){
var obj=document.getElementById("hidden");
if(obj.style.display==="block")
obj.style.display="none"
else
obj.style.display="block"
}
```

```html
<p id="hidden" style="display:none">I am the text<p>
<button onclick="func()">click me</button>
```

Comment: tell for more help

Comment: I can't believe how I miss this,

I already used === this for my if Statements but it never worked out.

Comment: dude, you don't know how much I changed my code just to figure this out. Thanks Man !

Comment: I can't at the moment, I need to wait 3 mins more for me to toggle it :'( 

-- sorry, my bad
wait a sec

Comment: Done :) 

It has a time duration for me to put a check on it 
thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is incorrect. Do it as following

```
obj.style.display === "block"
```

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison) you can find more about comparison operator in javascript

Answer (score 1):

You should use the comparison operators (`==` or `===`) in `if` statements, not the assignment operator (`=`)