# Javascript - More than one condition

Tags: javascript

I just started to learn JS and I want to ask about a task that I could not complete.

```
var balance = 325.00;
var checkBalance = true;
var isActive = false;

//The first question
if (checkBalance = true) {
        // the second question
        if(isActive = false) {
            console.log("Your account is no longer active.");

        } else if(isActive = true) {

            if(balance > 0) {
                console.log("Your balance is " + balance.tofix(2) +"$.");
            } else if(balance = 0) {
                console.log("Your Accunt is empty");  
            } else {
                console.log("Your balance is negetive, please contant bank");
            }
        }
    else {
        console.log("Thank you. Have a nice day");
```

The goal is to write an ATM and in order to do that I want to write more than one condition in the same time *(as you can see in the code)*.

1. Why this code doesn't work?
2. Is it possible to write if statement inside another if statement?
3. Is there a better solution?

Comment: `=` is assignment. To test equality, use `===`

Comment: You are on the right track, I added an answer with some explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you should use === for condition equal
your code:

```
if (checkBalance = true) {
```

correct is:

```
if (checkBalance === true) {
```

same for

```
if(isActive = false) {
```

correct is:

```
if(isActive === false) {
```

Comment: = is assign

=== is compare  in condition statement

Comment: @נירכליף Please read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

Answer (score 0):

= is assignment, == is used to check, change = to ==, === is used to check equality and type.

```
   if (checkBalance = true) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, it is indeed possible to write an `if statement` inside another one. But, you're missing a bracket and the way you check equality should be done differently. I edited your code so I can explain:

```
var balance = 325.00;
var checkBalance = true;
var isActive = false;

//The first question
if (checkBalance) {
    // the second question
    if(isActive = false) {
        console.log("Your account is no longer active.");

    } else if(isActive) {

        if(balance > 0) {
            console.log("Your balance is " + balance.tofix(2) +"$.");
        } else if(balance === 0) {
            console.log("Your Accunt is empty");  
        } else {
            console.log("Your balance is negetive, please contant bank");
        }
    }
else {
    console.log("Thank you. Have a nice day");
}
```

I mainly changed 2 things in your code. The first is changing

```
if (checkBalance = true)
```

Into this:

```
if (checkBalance)
```

**Edit 1: Shorter if statements**

You can omit the `= true` part because `checkBalance` is already a boolean value. This means that it is already `true` or `false`, which are values an `if statement` accepts. This brings me onto my second edit, which is the most important one.

**Edit 2: Checking for equality**

In your code, you use `= true` inside your `if statements`. Using only one `=` sign unfortunately is not checking for equality, but instead is your to assign values. You can only use one `=` when your assigning values like `var a = 1;`. Instead, you should use three `=` sings like `===`. This actually checks two things. First, it checks if the type of values are the same. Then, it checks if the values are equal. You can also use two `=` sings like `==`, this will check equality more loosely because it doesn't check if the types are the same. As noted in other answers, `===` is preferable here.

I hope this answers your question. If not, please comment below.

Answer (score 0):

First one:

```
= : is assign 
=== :is compare
```

One more thing wrong is :

```
balance.tofix(2)
```

It should be:

```
balance.toFixed(2)
```

and I just edited your code like this:

```
var balance = 325.00;
var checkBalance = true;
var isActive = false;

//The first question
if(!checkBalance) console.log("Thank you. Have a nice day");
else {
  if(!isActive) console.log("Your account is no longer active.");
  else{
    if(balance > 0) {
      console.log("Your balance is " + balance.toFixed(2) +"$.");
    } else if(balance = 0) {
        console.log("Your Accunt is empty");  
    } else {
        console.log("Your balance is negetive, please contant bank");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You've been given good answers on the syntax errors. Regarding 'is there a better way', the need for equality checking of `true` and `false` using `===` is not necessary, because the true/false is already implied in the `if` condition. You can use it as the variable by itself. Also, since it is a boolean that can only be true or false, using `if` and then `else` is totally fine to do. No need to do `if` and `else if`.

Using a helper function to handle your complex case makes your code much more readable.

```
var balance = 325.00;
var checkBalance = true;
var isActive = false;

//The first question
if (checkBalance) {
    // the second question
    if(isActive) {
        handleIsActive(balance);
    } else {
        console.log("Your account is no longer active.");
    }
} else {
    console.log("Thank you. Have a nice day");
}

function handleIsActive(balance) {
    if(balance > 0) {
        console.log("Your balance is " + balance.tofix(2) +"$.");
    } else if(balance === 0) {
        console.log("Your Accunt is empty");  
    } else {
        console.log("Your balance is negetive, please contant bank");
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this code is correct. You use `handleIsActive()` when the account is both active and when it's not. Also, you retained `if(balance = 0)` which is an assignment inside an if statement.

Comment: @NocNit Whoops, definitely made those mistakes. Thank you for poitning them out