# PHP If Statement is met display Either

Tags: php

I am familiar with using if else statement but my problem is how to display either if the condition is met.

```
if ($a == 1) {

echo 'B' OR 'C';  // just for reference

}
```

---

I have finally figure this out using nested loop

```
  if ($a == 1) {
    choiceresult = mt_rand(1,2)

   if (choiceresult == 1) {
      echo 'B';
   }

   if ( choiceresult == 2) {
      echo 'C';
   }

  }
```

Comment: "I am familiar with using if else statement " and yet you are using it wrong, its `==` not `=`. what determines when to echo `C` and when to echo `B` ?

Comment: look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: `=` is used for assignments, `==` or `===` are for comparisons.

Comment: if single line statement then you can use ternary condition like "echo ($a==1)?'B':'C';  "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: I already figure it up by using nested if

Comment: "I have finally figure this out using nested loop": there is no loop in the code you show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to fix your condition first :

```
if($a == 1)
```

Instead pf

```
if($a = 1)
```

Comment: my problem is not the equal but what comes after it whether I use  = == === for short how to display one result from