# What did i missed in code? PHP calculating

Tags: php

I want to send data to database, but if `result = 1` `status=plusone`, `result = 2` `status=plustwo`, etc..
It should work like that..
But no, it work like this: `result = 2` `status=plusone` .

What did i missed? Help me..

I've tried this:

```
$item = '0';

$result = $item + $points;
```

and:

```
$result = $points + 0;
```

Here is rest (part of) code:

```
if($result = 1){

 $Sql_Query  ="INSERT INTO points SET unique_id = '$id', description = '$Description', points = '$points', status= 'plusone'";
 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)) {
 echo 'Succcess!';

 }
}elseif($result = 2){

 $Sql_Query  ="INSERT INTO points SET unique_id = '$id', description = ' $Description', points = '$points', status= 'plustwo'";
  if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)) {

  echo 'Succcess!';

 }
}
```

Comment: use `==` for comparison in `if($result = 1)` and `elseif($result = 2)`, `=` is an assignment operator

Comment: Try adding an alert script in php to alret the value of result before executing the query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: thx its working now :)

Comment: @Master: Also take care of possible SQL injections. Just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` and `==` are different; `=` is for assignment, and `==` is to compare statement