# PHP - Multiple conditions in while statement

Tags: php, while-loop

For some reason this code won't run in my compiler.  The intention (as part of a larger project) is to ping a particular host 3 times, or until successful, whichever comes first.  It's not producing any errors, just terminating.  It works just fine if I remove the second condition from the while statement, but then I would need to have something more complicated to terminate the loop on a successful ping.  I haven't touched PHP in a while, so I'm probably missing something stupid.

```
<?php
function pingAddress($ip) {
//Set variable to limit loops and end if live
$pass = 0;
$result = 0;
//Create conditions for while loop
while( ( $pass < 3 ) && ( $result = 0 ) ) {
    //Count loops
    $pass++;
    //Execute ping
    $output=shell_exec('ping -n 1 '.$ip);
    //Display ping results for testing purposes
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
    //Check for "TTL" presence
    if(strpos($output, 'TTL') !== false)
    {
        //Notate positive result
        $result++;
        //Display for testing
        echo "Alive";
    }
    //Display negative result for testing
    else
    {
        echo "Dead";
    }
}
}


PingAddress("8.8.8.8");
```

Comment: Need a double == in `$result = 0`, this is just assigning 0 to $result not testing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: You could use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions to avoid this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll kick yourself:

```
while( ( $pass < 3 ) && ( $result = 0 ) ) {
```

Should use a double equals - it's a comparison, not an assignment:

```
while( ( $pass < 3 ) && ( $result == 0 ) ) {
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the second variable `$result`. Use [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) instead.

```
while($pass < 3) {
    //Count loops
    $pass++;
    //Execute ping
    $output=shell_exec('ping -n 1 '.$ip);
    //Display ping results for testing purposes
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
    //Check for "TTL" presence
    if(strpos($output, 'TTL') !== false)
    {
        //Display for testing
        echo "Alive";

        break; //exiting while loop
    }
    //Display negative result for testing
    else
    {
        echo "Dead";
    }
}
```

You can even write less code with

```
while($pass++ < 3) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second condition is written incorrectly. Change it to `$result === 0`

Answer (score 0):

Use equal operator not assign.

```
while( ( $pass < 3 ) && ( $result == 0 ) )
```

This should work.