# Nested if conditions doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have nested if conditions on my project but i have a problem;

```
if(isset($_GET['q']) && isset($_GET['t'])) {
  $query = $_GET['q'];
  $type = $_GET['t'];
  $none_key = FALSE;

  if($type = 'singer') {
      $singers = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM lyrica_singers WHERE singer_name LIKE '%$query%'");
      $control = $singers->rowCount();

      if($control > 0)  {
        $on_page = 24;
        $number_singers = $singers->rowCount();
        $number_page = ceil($number_singers/$on_page);

        $page = isset($_GET['p']) ? (int) $_GET['p'] : 1;
        if ($page < 1) $page = 1;
        if ($page>$number_page) $page = $number_page;

        $limit = ($page - 1) * $on_page;

        $singers = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM lyrica_singers WHERE singer_name LIKE '%$query%' ORDER BY singer_name ASC LIMIT ".$limit.",".$on_page);
        $singer_key = TRUE;
      } else {
        $none_key = TRUE;
      }
    }

    if($type = 'song') {
      $songs = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM lyrica_songs WHERE song_name LIKE '%$query%'");
      $control = $songs->rowCount();

      if($control > 0)  {
        $on_page = 24;
        $number_songs = $songs->rowCount();
        $number_page = ceil($number_songs/$on_page);

        $page = isset($_GET['p']) ? (int) $_GET['p'] : 1;
        if ($page < 1) $page = 1;
        if ($page>$number_page) $page = $number_page;

        $limit = ($page - 1) * $on_page;

        $songs = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM lyrica_songs WHERE song_name LIKE '%$query%' ORDER BY song_name ASC LIMIT ".$limit.",".$on_page);
        $song_key = TRUE;
      } else {
        $none_key = TRUE;
      }
    }
} else {
  $key = TRUE;
}
```

When I run the code, I am expecting that if one of the'control' variables is bigger than 0 the 'none_key' variable must be equal to 0. When the 'type' varible is 'song' there is no problem but if the  'type' variable is 'singer' then 'none_key' variable printing 1, I think it is running the second if block and becomes 'none_key' 1 because of the second 'control' variable is not bigger than zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an assignment, it sets `$type` to the value `singer`:

```
if ($type = 'singer') {
```

You want a comparison, it checks to see if `$type` equals the value `singer`:

```
if ($type == 'singer') {
```

**[Edit]** Some people prefer to write this sort of statement with the variable last. This is commonly called a "Yoda condition":

```
if ('singer' == $type) {
```

This way, if you screw up and only use one `=`, you get an error.

Comment: Another possible fix is to use a [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement where assignment is not going to happen by accident.

Comment: @tadman That seems unnecessary - at least 2-3 extra lines of code so you don't accidentally forget a single `=`?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It's a good way to handle multiple cases without piles of `if` statements. I don't mean for a single `if`, I mean for this specific situation where there's two comparisons, potentially more later.

Comment: @tadman Well that's definitely true, but with that said OP's code could easily be simplified to a much shorter amount of code (and still be readable, scalable) because there is a ton of code repetition.

Comment: I've been coding for hours and I really missed it, thank you so much.

Comment: Huh, I've never heard/seen Yoda Condition, but it does make sense, very interesting :)

Comment: Heh, I don't use them, they annoy me. I just use a PHPCS sniff to disallow embedded assignments.

Comment: I used to use Netbeans and it complained about assignment in conditionals if I remember correctly