# Why does the search always redirect to last if?

Tags: php, html

I need a piece of code that causes the user to put a name on a label and then click the search button, the user is redirected to a page of the name that the user searched for.

```php
//code to redirect
if (isset($_POST["procurar"])) 
    {
        $myPelourinho = $_POST['myPelourinho'];

        if ($myPelourinho="Oleiros") {
            header('location: oleiros.php');
        }
        if ($myPelourinho="Sertã") {
            header('location: serta.php');
        }
        if ($myPelourinho="Fundão") {
            header('location: fundao.php');
        }
        if ($myPelourinho="Proença-a-Nova") {
            header('location: proenca.php');
        }
        if ($myPelourinho="Vila Velha de Ródão") {
            header('location: vilavelhaderodao.php');
        }
        if ($myPelourinho="Sarzedas") {
            header('location: sarzedas.php');
        }
    }
```

```php
<!-- autocomplete and button -->
<form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="server.php" >
                <div class="autocomplete" style="width:245px;">
                    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myPelourinho" placeholder="Localidade">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="procurar" class="btn btn-default" stlye="width:50px">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
            </form>

<!-- autocomplete array list -->
var lista_pelourinhos = ["Fundão", "Proença-a-Nova", "Sarzedas", "Vila Velha de Ródão", "Oleiros", "Sertã"];
```

```javascript
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), lista_pelourinhos);
```

When I try this, it will always redirect to the last "if" (Sarzedas).

Comment: Use double equal signs '==' for comparison. Single '=' is for assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issues with the **=** and **==** operators. If you want the IF() to work properly, you have to use the **==** operator.

Code should be like that:

```
if (isset($_POST["procurar"])) 
{
    $myPelourinho = $_POST['myPelourinho'];

    if ($myPelourinho=="Oleiros") {
        header('location: oleiros.php');
    }
    if ($myPelourinho=="Sertã") {
        header('location: serta.php');
    }
    if ($myPelourinho=="Fundão") {
        header('location: fundao.php');
    }
    if ($myPelourinho=="Proença-a-Nova") {
        header('location: proenca.php');
    }
    if ($myPelourinho=="Vila Velha de Ródão") {
        header('location: vilavelhaderodao.php');
    }
    if ($myPelourinho=="Sarzedas") {
        header('location: sarzedas.php');
    }
}
```

For further info check [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)