# If condition A execute 1 OR if condition B execute 2 return not as expected

Tags: php, mysqli

`status` stored has value 'LET, SALE, LET/SALE'

My php code does not return as expected, I wish if ($input['status'] = "SALE") will return 'SALE, LET/SALE' but it return only LET/SALE

I have tried to amend the code many ways, but can't work probably

```
if (!empty($input['status']))

{
{
    if ($input['status'] = "SALE");
    {

    if (is_null($where))
    {
            $where = "WHERE";
    }
    else {
            $where = "AND";
    }

$query .= " $where status LIKE '%".$input['status']."%' AND `selling` <= 
{$input['max_price']}";
    }
}
{

    if ($input['status'] = "LET");
    {

    if (is_null($where))
    {
            $where = "WHERE";
    }
    else {
            $where = "AND";
    }

$query .= " $where status LIKE '%".$input['status']."%' AND `rental` <= 
{$input['max_price']}";
    }
}   

}
```

I wish to query property LET or SALE at condition max_price. Lets say if query SALE with max 100,000 return results shall include SALE, LET/SALE with max_price less than 100,000

Comment: One of the problems is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals .

Comment: Also I am not sure if ; should be placed after `if (...)`.

Comment: aside from the fact that you're using `=` the assignment operator on your if conditions, you're injecting your values directly into the statement which makes it vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: and you really don't need another nest of `if` inside your filters, just put `WHERE 1=1` on the initial statement, so that you can continually append `AND` in your condition along the filters, less code

Comment: OK tq @Ghost, will apply prepared statement later, currently the system only few of our team are using.

Comment: @user202729 thank you, the link you sent is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a value in your "if" statement.   Use `==` (is equal to) instead of `=` (equals).     What's happening is that it reassigns the value each time and stays at the last choice, which was LET/SALE

Change to:

```
if ($input['status'] == "SALE");
```

and do that for all of your "ifs"

Comment: == works, but only for "SALE". I use exactly same to "LET", it return no records found

Comment: I analyse the results returned, the value with "0" in SALE or LET not called.  (The default value for not for sale or not for rent is "0") Meaning if house A is for sale "100,000" and not for rent "0", house B is for sale "100,000" and for rent "1,500" then I call for SALE with max_price 100,000, the result return only house B.

Comment: this is not your only problem in your code.   why are you nesting your if statement inside many { } brackets?   You have extra unnecessary ones - clean it  up.    also, your second if statement (for LET) appears to be by itself?   instead of `if ($input['status'] == "LET");`  just use `else`.   If there's a third level (which we don't see), then use else if.

Comment: btw, you are also highly vulnerable to sql injection here.   You should not be including your variables directly in your query.   bind them and prepare them first.

Comment: what do you mean  "if statement (for LET) appears to be by itself ?"

Comment: if (!empty($input['status'])) 
     {if ($input['status'] == "SALE");
  { if (is_null($where))
        {$where = "WHERE";
        }
        else {
                $where = "AND";
        } 
    $query .= " $where status LIKE '%".$input['status']."%' AND selling <= 
    '{$input['max_price']}'";
  }
  else
  { if (is_null($where))
        {$where = "WHERE";
        }
        else {
                $where = "AND";
        }
      $query .= " $where status LIKE '%".$input['status']."%' AND rental <= 
    '{$input['max_price']}'";
  }
     }

Comment: I remove extra {} brackets and replace if ($input['status'] == "LET"); by else......seems the code dont run and stuck at the "else" link according to the error log

Comment: Guys, I have solved the problem......   below is the amended code                                                                    
if (!empty($input['status']) && ($input['status'] == "SALE"))
    
if (!empty($input['status']) && ($input['status'] == "LET"))                                                        others remain almost the same...

Comment: Thank you guys and I love you all. Cheers