# How to conditionally assign an object in PHP?

Tags: php, object, if-statement

I am new to PHP. I have a simple API written in PHP which receives the data in JSON. I am converting the JSON into a PHP array and parsing it:

```
$obj = json_decode($json,true);

$demircap = $obj['demircap'];
$disuzun1 = $obj['disuzun1'];
$boy = $obj['boy'];
$demiradet = $obj['demiradet'];
```

I would like to define a new empty object (`$disadet`) here and set a conditional state of the `$demiradet` object. If it has a special String value, I would like to give my new object `$disadet` as the double value of `$demiradet`, such that if `$disuzun1 == 'a'` , `$disadet == $demiradet*2`.

This is my code:

```
if ($disuzun1 == 'a' || $disuzun1 == 'b' || $disuzun1 == 'c'){
    $disadet == 2*$demiradet;
}else:
    $disadet == $demiradet;
```

How can I do this conditional formatting with PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals). `$disadet == 2*$demiradet;` should be using `=` not `==`. Same for `$disadet == $demiradet;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some logical errors, the problem is that your code "compiles" as in "is syntactically correct" but it's certainly not what you intended to do.

- `==` is a comparison operator, you want to use the assignment operator `=`
- `:` is used in python code blocks, in php you want to use braces `{ ... }` to define code blocks (such as an `else` code block)

So your code would be:

```
if ($disuzun1 == 'a' || $disuzun1 == 'b' || $disuzun1 == 'c'){ 
    $disadet = 2 * $demiradet;
} else {
    $disadet = $demiradet;
}
```

I would actually write this as:

```
$disadet = $demiradet; // assign the default value (no else required)
if ($disuzun1 == 'a' || $disuzun1 == 'b' || $disuzun1 == 'c'){ 
    $disadet = 2 * $demiradet;
}
```

Or, including [Ivan86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8202589/ivan86)'s answer to do easily maintainable "is-in-array" lookups:

```
$disadet = $demiradet; // assign the default value (no else required)
if (in_array($disuzun1, ['a', 'b', 'c'])){ 
    $disadet = 2 * $demiradet;
}
```

Comment: i think my fault was to use == operant, thanks, this works fine.

Comment: another question ; here the $demiradet seems a PHP Array object. Can i use arithmetic operator directly with this? or should i do a type conversion?

Comment: Even if you can, you wouldn't want to :-) What is the value of `$demiradet` if you try to `print_r($demiradet)` ?

Comment: i cannot print yet, because i call this api from a mobile app frontend. 
isnt it an array object? i need to send this to an sql query. but i still couldnt, and i thought this was because of data type.

Comment: You can print and look at the backend logs. If you are calling that API yourself then `$demiradet` will have the same type that you set it to in the json (i.e. array, string, int, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code like this:

```
if (in_array($disuzun1, ['a', 'b', 'c'])) {
    $disadet = 2*$demiradet;
} else {
    $disadet = $demiradet;
}
```

Also, when assigning a value to a variable you should use the assignment operator `=` and not the comparison operator `==`.

Comment: this solution is better to handle for longer arrays, thanks.

Comment: @canarcho it makes it easier to read for multiple values.