# Why is this "if" condition ignored?

Tags: php

The last if condition is ignored whereas one or both variables are equals to 0, can you explain me why ?

```
<?php
require('../controller/env.php');
$countexisting=0;
  if(!isset($_GET['idkey'])){
    header('location:../index.php');
    exit();
  }else{
    $idkey=$_GET['idkey'];
    $request=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM testimonials WHERE idkey=?');
    $request->execute(array($idkey));
    while ($exist=$request->fetch()) {
      $countexisting+=1;
      $activelink = $exist['activelink'];
    }

    if($countexisting=0 || $activelink=0){
      header('location:../index.php');
      exit();
    }
  }
```

Thanks !

Comment: `=` assign, `==`  equal, `===` identical. Have a look at [the three different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: @berend , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed the "==".

```
if($countexisting==0 || $activelink==0){
      header('location:../index.php');
      exit();
    }
```

it's working fine now!