# Populate entire list of MySql database table if no category is selected in query

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have created a function where query displaying database models correctly when chosen, however if no model selected then i want query to display entire list of models

I mean have database as

```
id
cat_name
cat_sorder for ascending or descending order
state
```

Here cat_name has different car manufacturers as
Honda
Tesla
Hyundai
Suzuki
Ford
VW etc

Now when in created function and choosing brand as say Tesla then its displaying correctly as tesla. But if i am not choosing any brand then its displaying 'No Category as shown in last line' which i want to change to display 'entire list of car brands.

**Surprise Elememt - this function working perfectly fine when php version changed to php 7.4, but in php 8.0 is not working as desired**

```
public function loadMainCat($brand,$Carmodel){
        $mainframe =JFactory::getApplication();
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        
        if($brand!=""){
            $query = "Select *  from #__newcar_categories Where id ='".$brand."' and state='1' Order By cat_sorder ";
        }else{
            $query = "Select *  from #__newcar_categories Where 1 and state='1' Order By cat_sorder ";
        }
        
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
        $list="";
        $flg=0;
        if($rows){
        $id='';
        $Desc=$this->loadSubCatDescr($id);
        $list.='<div class="listing-box">
                <div class="listing-box-left">
                <h4>Car Make</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="listing-box-middle">
               <h4> Model</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="listing-box-right">
                <h4><a href="#" onMouseover="ddrivetip(\'Ex-Showroom Delhi\')"; onMouseout="hideddrivetip()" style="color:#424141">Base Price Delhi</a></h4>
                </div>';
            foreach($rows as $row){
                $item_id = $this->getItemIdByName($row->cat_name);
                if($row->cat_image!=""){
                    $img = "uploads/categories/".$row->cat_image;
                }
                if($flg==0){
                    $cls="";
                    $flg=1;
                }else{
                    $cls="";
                    $flg=0;
                }
                
                $list.='<div class="listing-box-left"><p>'.$row->cat_name.'</p></div>
                        <div class="listing-box-middle">'.$this->loadSubCat($row->id,$Carmodel).'</div>';
            }
        $list.='</div>';
        }else{
            $list.='<div class="listing-box">No Category.</div>';
        }
        return $list;
    }
```

Now, If i modify function in this way where value of `if($brand!="") changed to if($brand="")` then yes then in event of no brand as selected, its displaying all brands, but even if select brand as Tesla then still its displaying all brands

```
public function loadMainCat($brand,$Carmodel){
        $mainframe =JFactory::getApplication();
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        
        if($brand=""){
            $query = "Select *  from #__newcar_categories Where id ='".$brand."' and state='1' Order By cat_sorder ";
        }else{
            $query = "Select *  from #__newcar_categories Where 1 and state='1' Order By cat_sorder ";
        }
        
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
        $list="";
        $flg=0;
        if($rows){
        $id='';
        $Desc=$this->loadSubCatDescr($id);
        $list.='<div class="listing-box">
                <div class="listing-box-left">
                <h4>Car Make</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="listing-box-middle">
               <h4> Model</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="listing-box-right">
                <h4><a href="#" onMouseover="ddrivetip(\'Ex-Showroom Delhi\')"; onMouseout="hideddrivetip()" style="color:#424141">Base Price Delhi</a></h4>
                </div>';
            foreach($rows as $row){
                $item_id = $this->getItemIdByName($row->cat_name);
                if($row->cat_image!=""){
                    $img = "uploads/categories/".$row->cat_image;
                }
                if($flg==0){
                    $cls="";
                    $flg=1;
                }else{
                    $cls="";
                    $flg=0;
                }
                
                $list.='<div class="listing-box-left"><p>'.$row->cat_name.'</p></div>
                        <div class="listing-box-middle">'.$this->loadSubCat($row->id,$Carmodel).'</div>';
            }
        $list.='</div>';
        }else{
            $list.='<div class="listing-box">No Category.</div>';
        }
        return $list;
    }
```

Pls help on how to achieve that

> If a brand is selected as showing in original function then correct brand is shown, but if no brand is selected then all brands in database should be shown instead of No Category as result

Thanks

Comment: remove 1 from else statment    $query = "Select *  from #__newcar_categories Where state='1' Order By cat_sorder ";

Comment: do you mean i should mention state as '0' then it will published in discontinued brands too.

Comment: No! here  [Where 1 and state=] change to [where state=]

Comment: Thanks but no change still showing 'no catergory'

Comment: You may have an issue with $db->loadObjectList(); 
 Can you test the 

Print_r($db->loadObjectList()); // What is the out put of this line

Comment: I'd like to see your Joomla questions posted on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange -- this is why that niche community was created in the first place.

Comment: `$brand=""` is an assignment. `$brand==""` is a loose comparison. `$brand===""` is a strict comparison.  [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2063480/2943403)  Also, I see `$img` being delcared, but never used.

Comment: Ok will try with $brand==="" but  this function working perfectly fine when php version changed to php 7.4, but in php 8.0 is not working as desired

Comment: If this issue is php-version-specific, then I'd say this is more of a Joomla issue.  Perhaps with `JFactory`.  I found [Working function in php 7.4 not working in 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74463638/2943403) while searching -- I guess you are pretty familiar with that page.  Perhaps look for some more debugging details. Dump your sql and result as a sanity check. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/27909/12352