# Why is php strpos to determine if text is contained in another string not working?

Tags: php, string, strpos

Here is my Code:

```
                $donor_comment_string = "BEN_W,NICOLA_M";

                if (strpos($donor_comment_string, 'NICOLA_M') != false) {
                echo 'TESTNicola';
                }
                                    if (strpos($donor_comment_string, 'BEN_W') != false) {
                echo 'TESTBen';
                }
```

I am using the above code which is Returning only TESTNicola.

I use the same function later on in a loop, checking it against an array of the Codes such as BEN_W and NICOLA_M and it is working down there.

Here is my real code minus the email.

```
                                                     $donor_comment_string = "BEN_W,NICOLA_M";

                $emails_array = array(
    array("Nicola", "ben@****.com", "Multi Campaign Donation Tester", "6666", "NICOLA_M"),
    array("Ben", "ben@****.com", "Multi Campaign Donation Tester", "0000", "BEN_W"),
    array("Test Name", "ben@****.", "Multi Campaign Donation Tester", "9999", "TEST_NOT"),
    
);
                for ($row = 0; $row < count($emails_array); $row++) {
                    if (strpos($donor_comment_string, $emails_array[$row][4], 0) != false) {
                        $participant_email = $emails_array[$row][1];
                        $participant_password = $emails_array[$row][3];
                        $campaign_name_string = "Campaign: " . $emails_array[$row][2];
                        $participant_name = $emails_array[$row][0];

                        $to = $participant_email;
                        $message_string = '';
                        $form_name = str_replace(" ", "_", "Marthon Donate To Multiple Participants");

                        if (isset($_POST[$form_name . $i])) {
                            $message_string = $_POST[$form_name . $i];
                        }
                        if ($message_string != "") {
                            $message_string = "\n\n" . $message_string;
                        }
                        if ($donor_comment_string != "") {
                            $donor_comment_string = "\nDonor Comment: " . $donor_comment_string;
                        }
                        //if ($message_string != "" && isset($_POST['date'.$i]) && $_POST['date'.$i] == $date.$i) {}

                        $msg = 'Hi ' . $participant_name . ",\n\n" .
                                'You have a new sponsor! ' . "\n\nDonor Name: " . $donor_name_string . "\nDonor Email: " . $donor_email_string . "\nAmount: " . $donor_amount_string . $message_string . "\n\nPlease feel free to email me if you have any questions. \nBen";
                        $msg_to_print = 'Hi ' . $participant_name . ',<br/><br/>' .
                                'You have a new sponsor: ' . "<br/><br/>Donor Name: " . $donor_name_string . "<br/>Donor Email: " . $donor_email_string . "<br/>Amount: " . $donor_amount_string . "<br/><br/>" . $message_string . "<br/><br/>Please feel free to email me if you have any questions. <br/><br/>Ben<br/><br/>";

                        if ($participant_email == '') {
                            echo'<br/><br/><hr/><li><b><span style="color:red;">Participant Email Error Contact Ben</span></b></li>';
                            $Email_reader->move(1, 'Error Email');
                        } else {
                            if (mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
                                $Email_reader->move(1);

                                echo '<br/><br/><hr/><li><span style="color:green;"><b>Following Email successfully sent to ' . $to . ':</b>';
                                echo '<br/><br/>' . $msg_to_print . '</span></li>';
                                $participant_email_to_store = $participant_email;
                                $donor_name_to_store = str_replace("\r\n", "", $donor_name[1]);
                                $donor_email_to_store = str_replace("\r\n", "", $donor_email[1]);
                                $donor_amount_to_store = str_replace("\r\n", "", $donor_amount[1]);
                                $donor_comment_to_store = 'None'; 

                                $array_for_storage = array(
                                    array(
                                        "participant_email" => $participant_email_to_store,
                                        "participant_password" => $participant_password,
                                        "participant_name" => $participant_name,
                                        "donor_name" => $donor_name_to_store,
                                        "donor_email" => $donor_email_to_store,
                                        "amount" => $donor_amount_to_store,
                                        "comment" => $donor_comment_to_store,
                                ));

                                $file = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/marathon/marathon-2024/marathon.json');
                                $data = json_decode($file);
                                unset($file); //prevent memory leaks for large json.
//insert data here
                                $data[] = $array_for_storage;
//save the file         
                                $json = json_encode($data);
                                //$json = str_replace("\r\n", "", $json);
                                file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/marathon/marathon-2024/marathon.json', $json);
                                //echo $json;

                                unset($data); //release memory
                            } else {
                                $Email_reader->move(1, 'Error Send');
                                echo'<br/><br/><hr/><li><b><span style="color:red;">Email Send Error Contact Ben</span></b></li>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This code is sending 2 emails and 2 outputs of the sent emails even with the above test data.

Comment: You would need to use `!==`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php says _"Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.

Returns false if the needle was not found.

Warning
This function may return Boolean false, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to false. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function."_

Comment: Since BEN_W starts at position 0, that strpos call returns 0, which is false-y and you didn't use type-safe comparisons so 0 == false and thus your condition isn't met. See also [The 3 different equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals)

Comment: It is now working with !==, but this doesn't explain why it was already working in the second code.

Comment: I just added the array code to my question

Comment: In your second (array-based) version it still only matches NICOLA_M. BEN_W still isn't matched - for exactly the same reason as before. Demo: https://3v4l.org/murK6 . It's unclear how you decided that this was "working"?? If it was matching BEN_W as well you'd see "Do Stuff" appear twice (obviously). Fixed version: https://3v4l.org/Air9O

Comment: Yes the array actually has emails and it is emailing to the BEN_W Email and NICOLA_M email but not the TEST_NOT Email. If I change TEST_NOT to BEN W it emails all 3

Comment: That description isn't reflected in the example you've provided us. As I proved with the demo, it will only "do stuff" for the NICOLA_M record. So unless the real code in the "do stuff" area which sends emails is also faulty in some way such that it sends things to extra people, then what you've shown us there cannot be a true reflection of the code/data you're actually executing with.

Comment: `If I change TEST_NOT to BEN W it emails all 3`....again, no it wouldn't, based on the data and code you've provided to us: https://3v4l.org/mW0Eu . Obviously if the `$donor_comment_string` contains something different you might get a different result, but you haven't told us that this is the case.

Comment: Well, recreating the real example as a test example for you has me flumoxed

Comment: I changed the example code to the actual code for the loop...

Comment: Thanks. It's because of `if ($donor_comment_string != "") {
      $donor_comment_string = "\nDonor Comment: ".$donor_comment_string;
    }`....why are you adding extra text to the donor comment string? You really ought to keep it intact so it's still the same next time you loop. If you want to make a piece of text for display, put that into a new variable. (The reason this is making it "work", in case it's not obvious, is because you're adding text at the start, so BEN_W is no found longer in the 0th position in the string, meaning the 0 == false problem no longer occurs)

Comment: Aha! Thanks a lot. Gosh that was painful.

Comment: Well As you can see the comment string is not used or echoed again in the loop. I used it in a earlier section of the code that is not looped, and I copied some of this section from it, so adding a string to the beginning of it doesn't effect the outcome in the other section.

Comment: OK.  So really it would make more sense to remove that `if ($donor_comment_string != "") {       $donor_comment_string = "\nDonor Comment: ".$donor_comment_string;     }` code and implement the `!==` test correctly